# Ensure that the Eclipse LogCat displays items relevant to my application

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

When I run my Android application in Eclipse on my machine, it automatically sets up a LogCat filter for my application, and only shows lines that are relevant to it.

However, running the same application on another PC (which happens to have Eclipse 'Mars') running on it, it just has one filter saying 'All messages (no filters)'.

Is there a setting somewhere to turn this on?

And incidentally, I know that I can set up a filter manually, but I liked the functionality that I had before, so I just want to turn that back on.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what IDE you use I would recommend you take a look at [pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat).

From the repo:

> Colored logcat script which only shows log entries for a specific application package.

You do need a bash terminal.

I will also recommend you move your project over to Android Studio.